# Testing zmq sockets with unittest

Tags: python, zeromq, python-unittest, pyzmq

I'm trying to test my messaging response in one of my libraries.

```
import unittest
from time import sleep

import zmq
from vexbot.messaging import Messaging


class TestMessaging(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.subscribe_address = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:4006'
        self.publish_address = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:4007'
        self.settings = {'subscribe_address': self.subscribe_address,
                         'publish_address': self.publish_address}

        context = zmq.Context()
        self.messaging = Messaging(self.settings, context)

        self.test_publish_socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
        self.test_publish_socket.connect(self.publish_address)

        self.test_subscribe_socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
        self.test_subscribe_socket.connect(self.subscribe_address)
        self.test_subscribe_socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')
        sleep(1)
```

My issue is that when I declare test methods in the above class, instead of calling the `setUp` function once and setting the state once, every test method tries recalls `setUp` to set it's own state and the address have already been snagged by the first instance.

How do I get around the multiprocess issues with the way `unittest` operates? Would it be better to call to a random socket for testing purposes?

Comment: If you only want it called once then put it in the constructor otherwise the purpose of setUp is to run before each and every test.

Comment: Haha, that makes a lot more sense. But the tests will still be run concurrently, correct?

Comment: Yes they will always run in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You should perform the zermq socket creation in the class constructor `__init__(self)`, which will be called once. `setUp()` is intended for things that should be done before every test.